# how = How.ID in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findby, page-factory

I've one small question, what's the difference beetween following lines in Selenium with Page Factory?

```
@FindBy(id = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

And

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the *JavaDocs* of [***Annotation Type FindBy***](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html) both the expression :

```
@FindBy(id = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

and

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

Both of the expressions points to the same element.

### Modifier [**How**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html)

**How** is defined in `org.openqa.selenium.support.How`, extends `java.lang.Enum<How>` and also implements `java.lang.Comparable<How>`.
The *Enum Constants* of **How** are as follows :

- [**CLASS_NAME**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#CLASS_NAME)
- [**CSS**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#CSS)
- [**ID**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#ID)
- [**ID_OR_NAME**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#ID_OR_NAME)
- [**LINK_TEXT**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#LINK_TEXT)
- [**NAME**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#NAME)
- [**PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT)
- [**TAG_NAME**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#TAG_NAME)
- [**UNSET**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#UNSET)
- [**XPATH**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/How.html#XPATH)

---

### Update

As per the counter question, if you have a look at the source code of the **enum How** it is defined as :

```
public enum How {
  CLASS_NAME {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.className(value);
    }
  },
  CSS {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.cssSelector(value);
    }
  },
  ID {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.id(value);
    }
  },
  ID_OR_NAME {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return new ByIdOrName(value);
    }
  },
  LINK_TEXT {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.linkText(value);
    }
  },
  NAME {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.name(value);
    }
  },
  PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.partialLinkText(value);
    }
  },
  TAG_NAME {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.tagName(value);
    }
  },
  XPATH {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return By.xpath(value);
    }
  },
  UNSET {
    @Override
    public By buildBy(String value) {
      return ID.buildBy(value);
    }
  };

  public abstract By buildBy(String value);
}
```

So for example when you implement **How** in conjunction with **ID** as per the following line :

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

**how = How.ID** functionally returns **By.id(value)** and is equivalent to what exactly the following line returns :

```
@FindBy(id = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
```

Hence we can conclude that **@FindBy(id = "foobar")** and **@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar")** are just 2 different way to achieve the same result and are available as per user's choice.

Comment: In other words, no real difference, which begs the question, why have both?

Comment: @BillHileman I have added an update as per your counter question. Let me know if you have any further counter questions.